# I was trying to access variable from one widget to another widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There is something very fundamentally wrong in this code please take a look at this. I'm also new to flutter so suggest me the correct path to proceed

I was trying to access this variable 'light' from class 'TurnOnSwitchAndSlider' to class 'BatteryIsChargedAsPerYourRequirement' and for some reason Im getting `ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppState> above this TurnOnSwitchAndSlider Widget`

turn_on_switch.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool light = true;
  double currValueForSlider = 85;

  void updateLight(bool value){
    light = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateSlider(double value){
    currValueForSlider = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class TurnOnSwitchAndSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const TurnOnSwitchAndSlider({super.key});

  @override
  State<TurnOnSwitchAndSlider> createState() => _TurnOnSwitchAndSliderState();
}

class _TurnOnSwitchAndSliderState extends State<TurnOnSwitchAndSlider> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Switch(
          value: context.watch<AppState>().light,
          onChanged: (bool value){
            context.read<AppState>().updateLight(value);
          },
        ),
        Slider(
          value: context.watch<AppState>().currValueForSlider,
          max: 100,
          divisions: 20,
          label: context.watch<AppState>().currValueForSlider.round().toString(),
          onChanged: (double value) {
            context.read<AppState>().updateSlider(value);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

battery_is_charged_as_per_your_requirement.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:battery_plus/battery_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_battery_lives/widgets/turn_on_switch.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class BatteryIsChargedAsPerYourRequirement extends StatefulWidget {
  const BatteryIsChargedAsPerYourRequirement({super.key});

  @override
  State<BatteryIsChargedAsPerYourRequirement> createState() => _BatteryIsChargedAsPerYourRequirementState();
}

class _BatteryIsChargedAsPerYourRequirementState extends State<BatteryIsChargedAsPerYourRequirement> {
  final Battery _battery = Battery();
  late Timer timer;
  int intBatteryLevel=0;
  String isChargedOrNot = '';
  int setBatteryPercentage = 85;
  bool boolShowAlert = true;
  
  BatteryState? batteryState;
  StreamSubscription <BatteryState>? batteryStateSubscription;

  Future<void> getBatteryLevel() async{
    final batteryLevel = await _battery.batteryLevel;
    setState(() {
      intBatteryLevel = batteryLevel;
    });
  }

  void updateBatteryState(BatteryState state){
    if(batteryState == state) return;
    setState(() {
      batteryState = state;
    });
  }

  void _showAlert(BuildContext buildContext){
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Remove the Charger!'),
        content: Text('Battery is now over $setBatteryPercentage, please remove the charger!'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(onPressed: (){
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }, child: const Text('Cancel!'))
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      getBatteryLevel();
      _battery.batteryState.then(updateBatteryState);
      batteryStateSubscription = _battery.onBatteryStateChanged.listen(updateBatteryState);

      bool light = context.watch<AppState>().light;
  
      if('$batteryState' == 'BatteryState.discharging' && intBatteryLevel < 40){
          isChargedOrNot = 'Connect the charger';
          boolShowAlert = true;
        }else if(intBatteryLevel == 100){
          isChargedOrNot = 'Battery is Charged to full';
          boolShowAlert = true;
        }else if(light){
          if('$batteryState' == 'BatteryState.charging' && setBatteryPercentage <= intBatteryLevel){
            isChargedOrNot = 'Battery is now over $setBatteryPercentage, please remove the charger!';
            if(boolShowAlert){
              _showAlert(context);
              boolShowAlert = false;
            }
          }
        }else{
          isChargedOrNot = 'Battery is now charging and is at $intBatteryLevel%';
          boolShowAlert = true;
        }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(isChargedOrNot,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          letterSpacing: 2.0,
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontFamily: 'SomeTypeMono',
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_battery_lives/widgets/Battery_Percentage_Text.dart';
import 'package:my_battery_lives/widgets/battery_is_charged_as_per_your_requirement.dart';
import 'package:my_battery_lives/widgets/turn_on_switch.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      useMaterial3: true,
    ),
    home: const Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String labelText = 'enable overcharge notification?';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Battery Warning',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'SomeTypemono',
        ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 180),
            Text(labelText,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                letterSpacing: 2.0,
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontFamily: 'SometypeMono',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            const TurnOnSwitchAndSlider(),
            const BatteryPercentageText(),
            const BatteryIsChargedAsPerYourRequirement(),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was trying to access light from `turn_on_switch.dart` to `battery_is_charged_as_per_your_requirement.dart`

I know I'm doing something so fundamentally wrong. I'm also new to flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I reading the documentation [here][https://pub.dev/packages/provider], it looks like you don't provide a provider to your app. You should have something like this in your main.dart

```
FutureProvider<AppState>(
  initialValue: our initial state,
  child: MyApp(),
)
```